# Displaying x - x of x articles on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently experiencing issues with a piece of code that displays the number of articles within that category and the amount of articles.

```
<?php
$my_tot_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
$my_curr_page = $paged;
    if($my_curr_page =='') $my_curr_page = 1;
    $my_finish =  $my_curr_page * get_option('posts_per_page');
    $my_start = 1 + $my_finish - get_option('posts_per_page');
?>
<p>Displaying <?php echo $my_start;?> - <?php echo $my_finish;?> of <?php echo $wp_query->found_posts;?> articles</p>
```

And this is currently displaying the following:

**Actual Result:**

Page 1: 
Displaying 1 - 1 of 3 articles

Page 2:
Displaying 2 - 2 of 3 articles

Page 3:
Displaying 3 - 3 of 3 articles

**Expected result:**

Page 1: 
Displaying 1 - 3 of 3 articles

Page 2:
Displaying 2 - 3 of 3 articles

Page 3:
Displaying 3 - 3 of 3 articles

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Think a moment about your actual and expected results. Try to imagine that with bigger numbers such as 10 articles per page and 30 articles overall. The actual result you get would be what I expect if I set the number of articles per page to 1.

Comment: Building on @Julian's comment: if you replace the `-` with `through` it will make more sense for what your code is currently doing with a posts per page set to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$wp_query->found_posts` to get the total amount of posts there are for a particular query. Have a look at [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for a list of all the member variables and how to use them